# plotting different administrative levels from same shapefie

Tags: r, ggplot2

Looking at GADM's shapefiles they have different administrative levels stored in the same file. Is it possible to chose which one determines the shape without changing line / fill color?

For example Bulgaria's shapefile: https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/shp/gadm36_BGR_shp.zip (and using gadm36_BGR_2 as the `file` after unzipping)

```
## Read shapefile
shp = readOGR(file, encoding = "UTC-8", use_iconv = FALSE)
shp@data$id = rownames(shp@data)
shpPts = fortify(shp, region="id")
shpDf = plyr::join(shpPts, shp@data, by="id")

ggplot(data = shpDf) + 
  aes(long, lat) + 
  geom_polygon(aes(group = group), color = 'grey', fill = 'white') +
  coord_map()
```

Makes this map 
[image]

Which is based off of NAME_2, can I draw the NAME_1 boundaries without changing the color of the lines or adding colored fill?

Comment: Not directly within `ggplot2`, no, because it was never meant for that. The `sf` package, on the other hand, facilitates polygon merging. (I answered a question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55183377/8449629) recently) In your case, though, the simplest approach is probably to read gadm36_BGR_1 instead of gadm36_BGR_2 as your shapefile, as that contains polygons at NAME_1 level.